# Passing a Text Stream from NodeJS to Browser

Tags: javascript, stream

I am trying to stream a text file processed in NodeJS to a browser.
The following is the text file before processing.
The file is named dbUsers.json.

```
{"userId":443,"email":"bob@gmail.com","hashedPassword":"36583a77a098c02ef111e2f2521d77b58e420f2bc7e9bf930ec24b21d42ea2e0","timeStamp":1567439821109,"deleted":false}
{"userId":447,"email":"alice@gmail.com","hashedPassword":"36583a77a098c02ef111e2f2521d77b58e420f2bc7e9bf930ec24b21d42ea2e0","timeStamp":1567439909013,"deleted":false}
{"userId":451,"email":"cliff@gmail.com","hashedPassword":"36583a77a098c02ef111e2f2521d77b58e420f2bc7e9bf930ec24b21d42ea2e0","timeStamp":1567443638340,"deleted":false}
...
```

After processing I am able to stream the data to a new file on the NodeJS server with the following commands:

```
// Create a writable stream and specify the file which will receive the data from the readable stream.
let destinationStream = fs.createWriteStream(_data.baseDir + '/dbPermissions/dbUsers' + '/' + 'test' + '.txt', {flags : 'a'});


pipeline
(
  sourceStream,
  destinationStream,
  function(error){if(error){console.log('There was an error.');}}
);
```

The new file shows the data processed as expected.
Some fields have been deleted and the records marked for deletion have been removed.
This demonstrates that sourceStream is functioning within NodeJS.
The data in the new file is now as follows:

```
{"userId":443,"email":"bob@gmail.com","timeStamp":1567439821109}
{"userId":447,"email":"alice@gmail.com","timeStamp":1567439909013}
{"userId":451,"email":"cliff@gmail.com","timeStamp":1567443638340}
...
```

Logging sourceStream to the NodeJS console before streaming it to the client browser produces the following output.

```
Readable {
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: [Object], tail: [Object], length: 45 },
     length: 3035,
     pipes:
      WriteStream {
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        path:
         'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Tutorials\\iotajs\\ias\\accounting\\/dbPermissions/dbUsers/test.txt',
        fd: null,
        flags: 'a',
        mode: 438,
        start: undefined,
        autoClose: true,
        pos: undefined,
        bytesWritten: 0,
        closed: false },
     pipesCount: 1,
     flowing: true,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: true,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: true,
     paused: false,
     emitClose: true,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: true,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events:
   [Object: null prototype] {
     close: [ [Function], [Function: onclose] ],
     end: [ [Function: onend], [Function] ],
     finish: [Function: onfinish],
     error: [Function: onerror],
     data: [Function: ondata] },
  _eventsCount: 5,
  _maxListeners: undefined }
Returning this response:  200
Returning this response:  200
```

When streaming sourceStream to the browser and then logging out to the browser's console, the output is the same as above.
So I am sure that sourceStream is getting to the client intact.

> The data I need to work with is probably locked up in the many
>   buffer properties of the object above, now called responseTextStream on
>   the client browser.
>
> My problem is that I don't know how to access the information in the
>   buffers nor do I know how to convert them from numbers back into text.
>
> The following is the function in the client browser where I am hoping
>   to use the data in the buffers. This is where I need help - I don't know how to access the stream. Thanks, John

```
// Populate the dbUsersList webpage with user records.
app.loadUsersListPage = function()
{  
  // Ask the server for the JSON records found in the dbUsers file.
  // Then run the callback function defined here which inserts rows into the usersListTable on the webpage
  // and populates them with data from the file of JSON records returned.
  app.client.request(undefined,'api/aUsers','GET',QueryStringObject,undefined,function(statusCode,responseTextStream)
  {
    // if the call to handlers._users.get which is mapped to api/aUsers called back success.
    if(statusCode == 200) 
    {
      // The streamed data can be seen on the console as a buffer full of numbers
      console.log(responseTextStream._readableState.buffer.head.data.data);

      // Create a handle which can be used to manipulate the table on the webpage.
      var table = document.getElementById("usersListTable");


      // The pseudocode below does not work but is shows what I hope to accomplish. 
      // The line below does not help to access the stream. This is where I need help.
      // What line or lines of code would facilitate access to the stream and allow 
      // processing it as a string, character by character, as shown below.
      var Astr = responseTextStream;

      var line = "";

      for(var i=0; i<Astr.length; i++)
      {
        var chr = String.fromCharCode(Astr[i]);
        if(chr == "\n" || chr == "\r")
        {
          // Look at each line of json at the console as it is consumed.
          console.log("line: ",line);

          // Turn the line, which is a json string, back into a json object 
          var recordObject = JSON.parse(line);

          if(recordObject)
          {
            // Insert a new row in the table.
            var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
            // Make the new row a member of the class 'checkRow'
            tr.classList.add('checkRow');

            // Insert five new cells into the new row.
            var td0 = tr.insertCell(0);
            var td1 = tr.insertCell(1);
            var td2 = tr.insertCell(2);   
            var td3 = tr.insertCell(3);          

            // load the new cells with data from the recordObject.
            td0.innerHTML = recordObject.userId;      
            td1.innerHTML = recordObject.email;
            td2.innerHTML = recordObject.timeStamp;      
            td3.innerHTML = '<a href="/users/edit?email=' + recordObject.userId + '">View / Edit / Delete</a>';
          } // End of: if(recordObject)

          // clear the line buffer to start the next line.
          line = "";

        } // End of: if(chr == "\n" || chr == "\r"){do stuff}
        else 
        {
            line += chr;
        }           

      }; // End of: for(var i=0; i<Astr.length; i++){...}

    } // End of: if the call to handlers._users.get which is mapped to api/aUsers called back successfully.

  }); // End of: app.client.request(undefined,'api/checks','GET'...

} // End of: app.loadUsersListPage = function(){...}
// End of: Populate the dbUsersList webpage with user records.
```

> According to the answer from @Brad I used his code with the same
>   unsatisfactory result. Below is Brad's code and below that is the
>   object that is returned by his code at the point where `value` is
>   logged to the console. It's the same object as before with the buffers
>   expanded for examination. My problem remains that the returned object
>   is just a bunch of buffers that contain a bunch of numbers and not
>   strings that I can do something with. When logging `value` to the
>   console I am hoping to see each line of the modified data in human
>   readable format. What am I not doing, or what am I doing wrong?
>   Thanks, John

```
// Populate the dbUsersList webpage with user records.
app.loadUsersListPage = async function()
{  
  // Define which users will be retrieved from dbUsers.json
  // This is not being used for now so all records will be retrived.
  var QueryStringObject = {};

  // Define a client function that calls for data from the server.
  const fetchPromise = fetch('api/aUsers')
  .then
  (
    (res) => 
    {
      // Verify that we have some sort of 2xx response that we can use
      if (!res.ok) 
      {
        throw res;
      }

      // If no content, immediately resolve, don't try to parse JSON
      if (res.status === 204) 
      {
        return;
      }

      // Initialize variable to hold chunks of data as they come across.
      let textBuffer = '';

      // This does not seem to be used. Delete this after everything else is working.
      const self = this;

      // Process the stream.
      return res.body

      // Decode as UTF-8 Text
      .pipeThrough
      (
        new TextDecoderStream()
      )

      // Split on lines
      .pipeThrough
      (
        new TransformStream
        (
          {
            transform(chunk, controller) 
            {
              textBuffer += chunk;

              const lines = textBuffer.split('\n');

              for (const line of lines.slice(0, -1)) 
              {
                controller.enqueue(line);
              } // End of: for (const line ...)

              textBuffer = lines.slice(-1)[0];
            }, // End of: Transform(chunk, controller){do stuff}

            flush(controller) 
            {
              if (textBuffer) 
              {
                controller.enqueue(textBuffer);
              } // End of: if (textBuffer)
            } // End of: flush(controller){do stuff}
          } // End of: parameters for new TransformStream
        ) // End of: call to constructor new TransformStream
      ) // End of: parameters for pipeThrough - Split on lines

      // Parse JSON objects
      .pipeThrough
      (
        new TransformStream
        (
          {
            transform(line, controller) 
            {
              if (line) 
              {
                controller.enqueue
                (
                  JSON.parse(line)
                ); //End of: call to controller.enqueue function
              } // End of: if (line)
            } // End of: transform function
          } // End of: parameter object for new TransformStream
        ) // End of: new TransformStream parameters
      ); // End of: parameters for .pipeThrough - Parse JSON objects
    } // End of: .then callback function instruction for fetch
  ); // End of: .then callback parameters for fetch


  // Call to function which asks server for data.
  const res = await fetchPromise;

  const reader = res.getReader();

  function read() 
  {
    reader.read()
    .then
    (
      ({value, done}) => 
      {
        if (value) {
          // Your object will be here
          console.log('I got to this point');
          console.log(value);
        }
        if (done) {
          return;
        }
        read();
      }
    );
  }

  read();

} // End of: app.loadUsersListPage = function(){...}
// End of: Populate the dbUsersList webpage with user records.
```

> This is what I get when Brad's code logs `value` to the console. It is
>   the same thing I got before. I was hoping to see lines of text. What
>   am I not doing, or what am I doing wrong? Thanks, John

```
{_readableState: {…}, readable: true, domain: null, _events: {…}, _eventsCount: 0}
domain: null
readable: true
_events: {}
_eventsCount: 0
_readableState:
awaitDrain: 0
buffer:
head:
data:
data: (65) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 52, 52, 51, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 98, 111, 98, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 52, 51, 57, 56, 50, 49, 49, 48, 57, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 52, 52, 55, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 97, 108, 105, 99, 101, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 52, 51, 57, 57, 48, 57, 48, 49, 51, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 52, 53, 49, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 99, 108, 105, 102, 102, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 52, 52, 51, 54, 51, 56, 51, 52, 48, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 52, 53, 53, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 109, 97, 114, 103, 101, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 52, 52, 51, 55, 54, 53, 54, 48, 57, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 52, 53, 57, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 99, 108, 105, 110, 116, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 52, 52, 51, 56, 49, 51, 49, 54, 55, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 52, 54, 51, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 98, 121, 114, 111, 110, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 52, 52, 51, 57, 52, 50, 48, 57, 54, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (68) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 52, 54, 55, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 109, 105, 108, 116, 111, 110, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 52, 52, 52, 50, 48, 55, 53, 52, 52, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (68) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 52, 55, 49, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 97, 114, 110, 111, 108, 100, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 52, 52, 52, 52, 50, 51, 57, 55, 53, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 52, 55, 53, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 115, 97, 108, 108, 121, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 52, 52, 56, 57, 56, 57, 52, 54, 57, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (68) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 52, 57, 49, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 109, 97, 114, 118, 105, 110, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 52, 53, 48, 51, 56, 50, 52, 54, 52, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 52, 57, 53, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 110, 97, 110, 99, 121, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 52, 53, 48, 52, 49, 55, 52, 52, 57, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (66) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 52, 57, 57, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 102, 114, 101, 100, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 52, 53, 48, 52, 51, 48, 55, 52, 50, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (66) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 48, 51, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 97, 108, 101, 120, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 52, 53, 52, 56, 55, 57, 55, 53, 51, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (68) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 48, 55, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 104, 101, 114, 109, 97, 110, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 53, 48, 54, 48, 50, 55, 50, 49, 55, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (69) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 49, 49, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 109, 97, 114, 103, 114, 101, 116, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 53, 53, 55, 53, 50, 49, 51, 55, 51, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (69) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 49, 53, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 115, 121, 110, 116, 104, 105, 97, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 53, 53, 55, 53, 55, 51, 56, 52, 48, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (68) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 49, 57, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 99, 111, 110, 110, 101, 114, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 53, 53, 55, 54, 48, 55, 51, 56, 55, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (68) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 50, 51, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 109, 97, 114, 103, 111, 116, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 55, 53, 53, 56, 53, 57, 57, 50, 48, 48, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 50, 55, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 100, 101, 110, 105, 115, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 48, 54, 54, 50, 56, 55, 53, 54, 48, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (66) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 51, 49, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 112, 104, 105, 108, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 48, 54, 54, 56, 49, 50, 48, 55, 48, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (68) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 51, 53, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 109, 111, 114, 103, 97, 110, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 48, 55, 55, 53, 55, 55, 56, 53, 56, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (66) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 51, 57, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 108, 117, 107, 101, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 49, 48, 55, 50, 53, 48, 49, 51, 55, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (68) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 52, 55, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 119, 97, 114, 114, 101, 110, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 49, 48, 56, 52, 55, 50, 54, 56, 52, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (68) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 53, 49, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 119, 105, 108, 98, 117, 114, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 49, 49, 49, 49, 56, 54, 51, 55, 54, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (66) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 53, 53, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 112, 97, 117, 108, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 52, 55, 57, 49, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (70) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 53, 57, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 102, 108, 111, 114, 97, 110, 99, 101, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 49, 53, 50, 50, 48, 48, 51, 50, 52, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (69) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 54, 51, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 109, 117, 109, 102, 111, 114, 100, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 49, 53, 50, 51, 55, 53, 57, 56, 50, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (66) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 54, 55, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 98, 97, 114, 116, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 49, 53, 55, 55, 48, 49, 57, 55, 49, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 55, 49, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 104, 111, 109, 101, 114, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 49, 53, 55, 55, 57, 48, 53, 49, 53, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (69) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 55, 53, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 102, 97, 108, 107, 110, 101, 114, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 49, 54, 51, 48, 52, 55, 52, 53, 52, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (70) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 55, 57, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 97, 110, 100, 101, 114, 115, 111, 110, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 49, 57, 54, 51, 56, 53, 50, 53, 51, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 56, 51, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 98, 97, 114, 114, 121, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 49, 57, 55, 55, 52, 54, 48, 55, 51, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (68) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 56, 55, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 98, 97, 114, 110, 101, 121, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 50, 51, 54, 54, 52, 54, 54, 54, 50, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 57, 49, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 98, 101, 116, 116, 121, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 50, 51, 54, 55, 52, 57, 54, 51, 54, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 57, 53, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 115, 116, 101, 118, 101, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 50, 52, 52, 56, 49, 56, 48, 50, 52, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (68) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 53, 57, 57, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 115, 104, 105, 114, 108, 121, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 50, 56, 49, 54, 49, 54, 50, 53, 52, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (66) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 54, 48, 51, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 109, 97, 103, 101, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 50, 56, 49, 56, 57, 54, 52, 50, 55, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (71) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 54, 48, 55, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 99, 111, 110, 115, 116, 97, 110, 99, 101, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 52, 50, 48, 54, 56, 49, 53, 54, 54, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (68) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 54, 49, 49, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 109, 97, 114, 115, 104, 97, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 52, 50, 48, 56, 55, 55, 57, 56, 54, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (66) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 54, 49, 57, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 103, 114, 101, 103, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 52, 50, 49, 49, 53, 55, 49, 56, 53, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 54, 50, 51, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 112, 101, 116, 101, 114, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 52, 50, 49, 50, 48, 55, 55, 51, 55, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (67) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 54, 50, 55, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 99, 105, 110, 100, 121, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 52, 56, 52, 52, 52, 49, 52, 54, 49, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (66) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 54, 51, 49, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 114, 111, 115, 101, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 52, 56, 52, 52, 55, 50, 49, 48, 57, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (66) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 54, 51, 53, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 98, 97, 114, 98, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 52, 56, 52, 53, 51, 57, 52, 50, 52, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next:
data:
data: (69) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 54, 51, 57, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 103, 105, 108, 98, 101, 114, 116, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 52, 56, 52, 53, 57, 56, 56, 54, 55, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next: null

length: 45
tail:
data:
data: (69) [123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 54, 51, 57, 44, 34, 101, 109, 97, 105, 108, 34, 58, 34, 103, 105, 108, 98, 101, 114, 116, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 83, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 49, 53, 54, 56, 52, 56, 52, 53, 57, 56, 56, 54, 55, 125, 10]
type: "Buffer"
__proto__: Object
next: null

I did not include the entire object.
```

> As seen above, many buffers are contained in the object returned.   I
>   think each buffer contains a line/record from the original dbUsers
>   file with some fields removed and duplicate records deleted.   I would
>   like to see these buffers as human readable text.   Because many
>   buffers are being returned, eventually I will need to learn how to
>   iterate through the buffers but for now I am just trying turn the
>   first buffer into text.   Brad at this point is at a disadvantage
>   because he is not near a computer.   So he can not see the code I am
>   using.  In any case, he kindly advised me to try the toString()
>   function.   So I tried the following line of code on the first buffer.
>   `console.log(value._readableState.buffer.head.data.data.toString());` 
>   The following numbers were the result.    I was hoping for a string of
>   text. Can anyone see what I am failing to do? Thanks, John

`123,34,117,115,101,114,73,100,34,58,52,52,51,44,34,101,109,97,105,108,34,58,34,98,111,98,64,103,109,97,105,108,46,99,111,109,34,44,34,116,105,109,101,83,116,97,109,112,34,58,49,53,54,55,52,51,57,56,50,49,49,48,57,125,10`

> After trying the following line of code I am still getting numbers not
>   letters at the console.
>   `console.log(value._readableState.buffer.head.data.data.toString('utf8'));`
>   Thanks, John

Comment: What sort of browser compatibility do you require?  I just did something recently with this exact format... NDJSON streams, being handled nicely with TransformStream client-side.  Unfortunately, it isn't the most compatible API available.

Comment: Hi @Brad, I am using a chrome browser. All other users will be using the same. Sadly, I am not using any dependencies for security reasons.
[The open source project is found here.](https://github.com/johnshearing/IOTA-Secure-Airgapped-Accounting-and-Banking-System)
Thanks

Comment: After applying @Brad's code the result was the same. 
When logging `value` to the console, I am seeing buffers full of numbers and not lines of text. What do I need to do to see lines of text when `value` is logged to the console. Thanks, John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using Chrome, you get to use all the new goodness like TextDecoderStream and TransformStream in a nifty pipeline that streams data from the HTTP response and decodes that line-delimited JSON as it does it.  Check this out:

```
const fetchPromise = fetch(url, params).then((res) => {
  // Verify that we have some sort of 2xx response that we can use
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw res;
  }

  // If no content, immediately resolve, don't try to parse JSON
  if (res.status === 204) {
    return;
  }

  let textBuffer = '';

  const self = this;

  return res.body
    // Decode as UTF-8 Text
    .pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream())

    // Split on lines
    .pipeThrough(new TransformStream({
      transform(chunk, controller) {
        textBuffer += chunk;
        const lines = textBuffer.split('\n');
        for (const line of lines.slice(0, -1)) {
          controller.enqueue(line);
        }
        textBuffer = lines.slice(-1)[0];
      },
      flush(controller) {
        if (textBuffer) {
          controller.enqueue(textBuffer);
        }
      }
    }))

    // Parse JSON objects
    .pipeThrough(new TransformStream({
      transform(line, controller) {
        if (line) {
          controller.enqueue(
            JSON.parse(line)
          );
        }
      }
    }));
});
```

Now, you can consume this new object stream like any other:

```
  const res = await fetchPromise;
  const reader = res.getReader();
  function read() {
    reader.read().then(({value, done}) => {
      if (value) {
        // Your object will be here
      }
      if (done) {
        return;
      }
      read();
    });
  }
  read();
```

(Note:  I haven't tested this code in this example context... I modified this from one of my projects, so please look it over and adapt it for your specific purposes.)

Comment: Sorry, @Brad. The result using your code is exact the same as the result before. I have updated my question to display your code as it was used and the resulting object that was returned when your code logs `value` to the console. I was hoping to see lines of text not buffers of numbers. Did I miss something in your answer. Thanks, John

Comment: @JohnShearing Call `toString()` on the buffer.  Not at a computer at the moment so I can't really see in the code where the decoding step is getting missed, but what you have is a binary buffer of a JSON string.  Some step is missing.

Comment: Thanks @Brad, 
There are many buffers in the object returned. 
So after getting past the problem of turning a buffer back into text, I will need to learn how to iterate through all the buffers. 
So for now I just tried to read the first buffer using the following line of code as you suggested.
`console.log(value._readableState.buffer.head.data.data.toString());`
The result was numbers and not a human readable string as hoped.
I would be grateful if you could have a look next time you are near a computer.
Thanks, John

Comment: Hi @Brad, I just tried this with the same result. I am still getting numbers not letters at the console.
`console.log(value._readableState.buffer.head.data.data.toString('utf8'));`
Thanks, John

Comment: BTW, I am super grateful for Brad's code because it is my first exposure to promises and async/await.

Comment: @JohnShearing Any way you could post this up at JSFiddle?  Maybe, mock the API source somehow if needed?  (Such as by uploading a static JSON file somewhere, to be requested by the script over at JSFiddle.)  I can't tell off the top of my head but it seems like the wrong stream is working its way up the promise chain somewhere.  Also, if you set breakpoints or `console.log()` in the middle of the place where we split on lines, do you see lines there?  Are we even reaching that point?

Comment: Hi @Brad, Yes I can post this on JSFiddle but I will take a few days because I have never done that before. In the mean time I am logging to console at the for loop. The following produces no output.
```for (const line of lines.slice(0, -1))
              {
                console.log('This is the line sliced: ', line);
                controller.enqueue(line);
              } // End of: for (const line ...)
```
But changing the negative one to a positive one produces an object with 7 buffers. There is one buffer for each line in my original dbUsers file.

Comment: Also @Brad, Just pushed everything as it is now to github.
```
https://github.com/johnshearing/IOTA-Secure-Airgapped-Accounting-and-Banking-System
```
In app.js is the function `app.loadUsersListPage`. This is your code if I did everything correctly.
In server.js is the function `unifiedServer`. This calls `handlers._users.get` in the file aHandler.js

Comment: Finally, I should mention that dbUsers is found here. `accounting\dbPermissions\dbUsers`. Thanks, John

Comment: You were right @Brad. The wrong stream was working it's way up. Your code works perfectly. I will push everything up to github tomorrow morning and make a full report here tomorrow morning as well. Thanks so much for the help, John

Comment: @JohnShearing Cool, glad you figured out where the issue was!

Comment: Everything is now pushed to github. Will make a report here tomorrow morning.

Comment: Looks like your function doesn't `return` anything? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897018/sorting-data-fetched-asynchronously-with-javascript-fetch-api

Comment: @Bergi What function?  The top part returns a promise to push data through parts.  The bottom part is expecting someone to implement something where it says `// Your object will be here`.

Comment: @Brad Yeah, but ultimately a `read()` call should return a promise for the result.

Comment: @Bergi No, that's not what I'm intending here.  The goal is to deal with streaming it as it comes in... that's the whole purpose.  So, the implementer should take this and extend it as they see fit, to deal with the streaming data.

Comment: Still, they should have the ability to accumulate the data as it comes in, and then return a final value when the stream ends. At least that's what the OP needs in his latest question…

Comment: @Bergi This question, the one I answered, demonstrates one possible way to stream data from an HTTP resource.  What you do with the result is up to you.  If streaming it and processing it as it comes in isn't appropriate, then this whole method is unnecessary and far overly complicated.  A normal `fetch()` would do.  And, I haven't read, nor responded to the question you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Brad's JavaScript from above which runs in the browser worked perfectly.
The problem was the way in which the stream had been sent from the NodeJS server to the browser.
All the working code has been pushed to github.
[Click here to see the full repository which uses no dependencies.](https://github.com/johnshearing/IOTA-Secure-Airgapped-Accounting-and-Banking-System)

> [The action starts here with the function called loadUsersListPage](https://github.com/johnshearing/IOTA-Secure-Airgapped-Accounting-and-Banking-System/blob/master/public/app.js)
>   The function is listed below for convenience.
>   This is Brad's code which requests a stream of text from the server and then consumes the stream to populate a webpage with a list of users from the dbUsers table on the server.

```
// Populate the dbUsersList webpage with user records.
app.loadUsersListPage = async function()
{  
  // Create a handle which can be used to manipulate the table on the webpage.
  var table = document.getElementById("usersListTable");  

  // Define which users will be retrieved from dbUsers.json
  // This is not being used for now so all records will be retrived.
  var QueryStringObject = {};

  // Define a client function that calls for data from the server.
  const fetchPromise = fetch('api/aUsers')
  .then
  (
    (res) => 
    {
      // Verify that we have some sort of 2xx response that we can use
      if (!res.ok) 
      {
        // throw res;
        // Show 'you have no checks' message
        document.getElementById("noChecksMessage").style.display = 'table-row';

        // Show the createCheck CTA
        document.getElementById("createCheckCTA").style.display = 'block';

        console.log("Error trying to load the list of users: ");        
      }

      // If no content, immediately resolve, don't try to parse JSON
      if (res.status === 204) 
      {
        return;
      }

      // Initialize variable to hold chunks of data as they come across.
      let textBuffer = '';

      // Process the stream.
      return res.body

      // Decode as UTF-8 Text
      .pipeThrough
      (
        new TextDecoderStream()
      )

      // Split on lines
      .pipeThrough
      (
        new TransformStream
        (
          {
            transform(chunk, controller) 
            {
              textBuffer += chunk;            

              // Split the string of records on the new line character and store the result in an array named lines.
              const lines = textBuffer.split('\n');

              // Cycle through all elements in the array except for the last one which is only holding a new line character.
              for (const line of lines.slice(0, -1))
              {
                // Put the element from the array into the controller que.
                controller.enqueue(line);
              } // End of: for (const line ...)

              // Put the last element from the array (the new line character) into the textBuffer but don't put it in the que.
              textBuffer = lines.slice(-1)[0];             
            }, // End of: Transform(chunk, controller){do stuff}

            flush(controller) 
            {
              if (textBuffer) 
              {
                controller.enqueue(textBuffer);
              } // End of: if (textBuffer)
            } // End of: flush(controller){do stuff}
          } // End of: parameters for new TransformStream
        ) // End of: call to constructor new TransformStream
      ) // End of: parameters for pipeThrough - Split on lines

      // Parse JSON objects
      .pipeThrough
      (
        new TransformStream
        (
          {
            transform(line, controller) 
            {
              if (line) 
              {
                controller.enqueue
                (
                  JSON.parse(line)
                ); //End of: call to controller.enqueue function
              } // End of: if (line)
            } // End of: transform function
          } // End of: parameter object for new TransformStream
        ) // End of: new TransformStream parameters
      ); // End of: parameters for .pipeThrough - Parse JSON objects
    } // End of: .then callback function instruction for fetch
  ); // End of: .then callback parameters for fetch


  // Call to function which asks server for data.
  const res = await fetchPromise;

  const reader = res.getReader();

  function read() 
  {
    reader.read()
    .then
    (
      ({value, done}) => 
      {
        if (value) 
        {
          // Your object (value) will be here

          // Insert a new row in the table.
          var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
          // Make the new row a member of the class 'checkRow'
          tr.classList.add('checkRow');

          // Insert five new cells into the new row.
          var td0 = tr.insertCell(0);
          var td1 = tr.insertCell(1);
          var td2 = tr.insertCell(2);   
          var td3 = tr.insertCell(3);          

          // load the new cells with data from the recordObject.
          td0.innerHTML = value.userId;      
          td1.innerHTML = value.email;
          td2.innerHTML = value.timeStamp;      
          td3.innerHTML = '<a href="/users/edit?email=' + value.userId + '">View / Edit / Delete</a>';
        } // End of: if(value){do stuff}

        if (done) {return;}

        read();

        // Show the createCheck CTA
        document.getElementById("createCheckCTA").style.display = 'block';
      } // End of: if a record object (value) is returned.
    ); // End of: .then callback after read function completes.
  } // End of: function definition: function read(){do stuff}

  // Call the read function defined above.
  read();

} // End of: app.loadUsersListPage = function(){...}
// End of: Populate the dbUsersList webpage with user records.
```

> [The working server code is found here under the function named unifiedServer](https://github.com/johnshearing/IOTA-Secure-Airgapped-Accounting-and-Banking-System/blob/master/lib/server.js)
>   The function is listed directly below for convenience.
>   This function routes the request to a handler (also listed below) and then sends the
>   stream of returned data back to the browser for Brad's code to
>   consume.
>   Near the bottom of the function you can see a pipeline is used to send the stream to the browser.
>   This is what I was missing.

```
// Define a function to route requests from the client to the handler and to serve back a response.
// All the logic for both the http and https server
server.unifiedServer = function(req, res)
{
  // Get the URL and parse it.
  var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);

  // Get the path from the URL.
  var path = parsedUrl.pathname;
  var trimmedPath = path.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '');

  // Get the query string as an object.
  var queryStringObject = parsedUrl.query;

  // Get the http method.
  var method = req.method.toLowerCase(); 

  // Get the headers as an Object
  var headers = req.headers;

  // Instantiate decoder that will turn payload buffer into a string.
  var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');

  // Create an empty string for the request payload. 
  // It's called buffer but it is not a JavaScript buffer (not binary data) - it's just an empty string.
  // We are going to use it to hold the request payload buffer after it has been decoded and turned into a string.
  var buffer = '';


  // Call to event emitter req.on('data...
  // Watch for a chunk of data from the client's request payload buffer. 
  // The run the callback defined below with the returned data.
  req.on('data', function(data)
  {
    // Decode the chunk and write it to the payload string.
    buffer += decoder.write(data);
  });


  // Call to event emitter req.on('end...    
  // Watch for the end of the payload from the client request.
  // The callback defined here is the action taken after the entire request has been received.
  req.on('end', function()
  {
    // Finish writing to the buffer.
    buffer += decoder.end();


    // Choose the handler the client's request should go to.
    // If one is not found, use the notFound handler.
    // To be clear: A key in the router object below should match the request from the client.
    // chosenHandler becomes an alias for the handler function which is mapped to the key in the router object.
    // This is how we can refer to the handler function without knowing what it is in advance.
    var chosenHandler = typeof(server.router[trimmedPath]) !== 'undefined' ? server.router[trimmedPath] : aHandlers.notFound;

    // If the request is within the public directory, use the public handler instead of what was assigned by the line above.
    // The line below is required because the line above will only match a handler to a client request if
    //   the request exactly matches one of the keys in the request router object at the bottom of this file. 
    //   So if the request is "public" then we have a match with the public handler. But request 
    //   public/app.css would not be matched with a handler.
    chosenHandler = trimmedPath.indexOf('public/') > -1 ? handlers.public : chosenHandler;

    // Construct the data object to send to the handler.
    var data = 
    {
        'trimmedPath' : trimmedPath,
        'queryStringObject' : queryStringObject,
        'method' : method,
        'headers' : headers,
        'payload' : aHelpers.parseJsonToObject(buffer) 
    }; // End of: Construct the data object to send to the handler.

    // Call the handler specified by the client. 
    // Then execute the callback we are passing in as an argument.
    chosenHandler(data, function(statusCode, payload, contentType)
    {
      // Determine the type of response - default to json.
      contentType = typeof(contentType) == 'string' ? contentType : 'json';

      // Use the status code called back by the handler, or default to 200.
      statusCode = typeof(statusCode) == 'number' ? statusCode : 200;


      // Return the response parts that are content specific.
      var payloadString = '';

      if(contentType == 'json')
      {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');    

        // Use the payload called back by the handler, or default to an empty object.
        payload = typeof(payload) =='object' ? payload : {};     

        // Convert the payload to a string.
        payloadString =  JSON.stringify(payload);       
      }

      if(contentType == 'html')
      {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');       
        payloadString = typeof(payload) == 'string' ? payload : '';   
      }     

      if(contentType == 'favicon')
      {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/x-icon');       
        payloadString = typeof(payload) !== 'undefined' ? payload : '';   
      }  

      if(contentType == 'css')
      {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/css');       
        payloadString = typeof(payload) !== 'undefined' ? payload : '';   
      }  

      if(contentType == 'png')
      {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');       
        payloadString = typeof(payload) !== 'undefined' ? payload : '';   
      }  

      if(contentType == 'jpg')
      {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');       
        payloadString = typeof(payload) !== 'undefined' ? payload : '';   
      }  

      if(contentType == 'plain')
      {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');       
        payloadString = typeof(payload) !== 'undefined' ? payload : '';
      }       

      // Return the response parts that are common to all content-types.      

      res.writeHead(statusCode); 

      if (contentType == 'stream')
      {
        pipeline
        (
          payload,
          res,
          function(error){if(error){console.log('There was an error.');}}
        );
      }
      else
      {
        res.end(payloadString);
      }

      console.log('Returning this response: ', statusCode);
    }); // End of: call to chosenHandler(...
  }); // End of: call to req.on('end', function(...
}; // End of: var unifiedServer = function(...
// End of: Define a function to route requests from the client to the handler and to serve back a response.
```

> The handler function which:
>   reads data from the dbUsers.json file,
>   processes the data,
>   and returns it as a stream
>   [can be found here under the name handlers._users.get](https://github.com/johnshearing/IOTA-Secure-Airgapped-Accounting-and-Banking-System/blob/master/lib/aHandlers.js)
>   The function is listed below for convenience.

```
handlers._users.get = function(data, callback)
{
  // Create an empty map data structure which will be used to merge user records with the same email address.
  let usersMap = new Map();

  // This function sets up a stream where each chunk of data is a complete line in the dbUsers file.
  let readInterface = readline.createInterface
  (
    { // specify the file to be read.
      input: fs.createReadStream(_data.baseDir + '/dbPermissions/dbUsers' + '/' + 'dbUsers' + '.json'),
    }
  );


  // Look at each record in the file.
  readInterface.on('line', function(line) 
  {
    // Convert the JSON string (a single line from the dbUsers file) into lineValueObject.
    // These objects will written back to a new file after deleting some un-needed key/value pairs.
    let lineValueObject = JSON.parse(line);       

    // Declare a variable to serve as a key in the map to manage the lineValueObject.
    let userId = lineValueObject.userId;          

    if(lineValueObject.deleted === true)
    {
      // Remove this record from the map 
      usersMap.delete(userId);
    }
    else // this record has not been marked for deletion.
    {
      // Remove the hashed password key/value pair from the lineValueObject before returning it to the requester.
      delete lineValueObject.hashedPassword; 

      // Remove the deleted key/value pair from the lineValueObject before returning it to the requester.
      delete lineValueObject.deleted;            

      // Update this record in the map.
      usersMap.set(userId, lineValueObject);
    }

  }); // End of: readInterface.on('line', function(line){...}
  // End of: Look at each record...


  // This listener fires after we have looked through all the records in the dbUsers file.
  // The callback function defined here will stream the list of users back to the clients browser.
  readInterface.on('close', function() 
  {          
    // This readable stream will be used to write the result of the merge to a new file.
    const sourceStream = new Readable(); 

    for (const [key, valueObject] of usersMap)
    {
      // Convert the data object to a string.
      let stringData = JSON.stringify(valueObject);     

      // Load the readable stream with data.
      sourceStream.push(stringData + '\n');                  
    }       

    // Tell the stream no more data is coming.
    sourceStream.push(null);     

    callback(200, sourceStream, 'stream');             

  }); // End of: readInterface.on('close', function(){...}   

}; // End of: handlers._users.get = function(data, callback){do stuff}
```